# Run php function by Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, oop, cookies

I have button on html like this:

```
<button class="uk-button uk-button-primary uk-modal-close confirm-rules" type="button" onclick="sendStatus('accept_rules')">Rozumiem</button>
```

and I want to do it when I click on the button, the function in php will be called.
I try do this by ajax like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function sendStatus(status) {
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "Controllers/Core/Dashboards/Admin/Dashboard.php",
            data: { status: status }
        }).done(function( msg ) {
            alert("Cookie saved:" + msg );
        });
    }
</script>
```

The problem is with php file, because it's look like this:

```
    <?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Controllers\Core\Dashboards\Admin;

use App\Controllers\Controller;

use App\Core\SessionManagement;
use App\Core\Request;
use App\Core\Cookies;

class AdminDashboard extends Controller
{

    private $cookies;

    /**
     * AdminDashboard constructor.
     * @param Cookies $cookies
     */
    public function __construct(Cookies $cookies)
    {
      $this->cookies = $cookies; 
    }

    public function acceptDashboardBox()
    {
        if ( isset($_POST['status']) )
        {
            $this->cookies->add( $_POST['status'], 'true', 'time() + (365 * 24 * 60 * 60)');
        }
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    public function index() : void
    {

        Controller::renderView('Core/Dashboards/Admin/Dashboard');

    }

}
```

Button must run function acceptDashboardBox() on class AdminDashboard.
How i can do this?

Comment: What framework is this `App\Controllers\Controller`  CI?  In any case typically with a MVC framework you would never call `Dashboard.php` directly, instead you would call `Dashboard` or without HTACCESS it would actually be something like `index.php/Dashboard` then the framework would route it into a controller.  So I am confused.

Comment: I used my own framework. I'm just learning mvc and object oriented programming  that's why I do not use ready-made frameworks yet.

Comment: One key thing of any framework is an entry point, a common place all requests must go through, this allows you to "load" your framwork no matter the request.  Everything should go though the entry point, then a router delegates it to be handled by the proper controller. I have an example of a simple router on [GitHub](https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/MISC/tree/master/Router)

Answer (score 0):

When calling your file `Controllers/Core/Dashboards/Admin/Dashboard.php`, nothing will happen because nothing calls the function `acceptDashboardBox()` or anything else in this file.

Please always make sure that your PHP Classes do have the name of the file that you are currently in ([PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/)). The name of your class is `AdminDashboard`, so call your file `AdminDashboard.php` to avoid confusion. Also it is common practice to use [Event Listeners](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp) for click events instead of calling a function `onclick=`.

To let PHP only call your function `acceptDashboardBox()` you would need a new endpoint/file that does that same as your function and nothing else.

I would suggest you return a json with a status and catch exceptions that set the status if one occurs to something that indicates an error occurred. You can check the json in your javascript and check if the operation was successful or not. Something like:

```
{
    status: "success"
}
```

OR

```
{
    status: "failure"
}
```

would do the deal.